Axios post to Spring Boot
I've tried to post data from Front-end with ReactJS to Backend Spring Boot, but it has AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500.
Could you tell me what's wrong with my code? Why can't I post new product to backend?
Here is my code:
Backend:
Product Controller
package com.tranxuanphong.example04.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.tranxuanphong.example04.entity.Product;
import com.tranxuanphong.example04.service.ProductService;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("api/products")
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:3000"}, exposedHeaders = "Content-Range")

public class ProductController {

    private ProductService productService;

    // Create Product REST API
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Product> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        Product savedProduct = productService.createProduct(product);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedProduct, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    // Get All Products REST API
    // http://localhost:8080/api/Products
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts() {
        List<Product> products = productService.getAllProducts();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(products, HttpStatus.OK);
    }    
}

React: Product.js
const createProduct = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      
        if (title !== "" || body!== "" || price !== "" || category !== "0" || photo !== "") {
            let product = {
                title: title,
                description: body,
                price: price,
                photo: photo,
                category_id: parseInt(category)
            }

            POST_ADD_PRODUCT(`products`, product).then(item => {
                // console.log('item:',item);
                if(item.data===1){
                    setCheckAdd(true);
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            alert("Not enough information");
        }
    }

React: apiService.js
export function callApi(endpoint, method = 'GET', body) {
    return axios({
        method: method,
        url : `${API_URL}/${endpoint}`,
        data : body,   
    })      
    .catch(e => {   
        console.log(e)
    })
}

export function POST_ADD_PRODUCT (endpoint, data) {
    return callApi(endpoint, "POST", data);
}

I've been trying to post this from my Frontend ReactJS to Backend all day, but I can't. However, I tried Postman, and it worked fine with post and get so I think my Frontend has some problems.

Status code 500 means the error happened in the back end. Check your spring boot app logs for any errors.

Here are few things that you can try:

Look the logs in spring boot application
Check the sent request in developer tools and ensure that the data sent is correct
You can also copy the sent request by right click > copy by curl(bash) and import in Postman and try to resend the request to see if the same request works through postman

